# Dapper Parameter Length

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dapper

Not sure if this is related to Dapper use or not. On a SQL Server where Dapper is use, I see multiple cached plans being generated with the only difference being the length of parameter:

```
(@parentId uniqueidentifier,@childName nvarchar(60)) 
 SELECT [ID] FROM [Items] WHERE [ParentID] = @parentId AND [Name] = @childName

(@parentId uniqueidentifier,@childName nvarchar(91))
SELECT [ID] FROM [Items] WHERE [ParentID] = @parentId AND [Name] = @childName

(@parentId uniqueidentifier,@childName nvarchar(15))
 SELECT [ID] FROM [Items] WHERE [ParentID] = @parentId AND [Name] = @childName
```

Are there any Dapper config settings which control parameter length? Can it be set to a fixed length `nvarchar(256)` matching the table column definition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define length when passing argument:

```
new {childName = new DbString { Value = "SomeValue", Length = 256, 
                               IsAnsi = false, IsFixedLength = false }};
```

Comment: What's the `IsFixedLength` parameter for?

Comment: Ok I found out what it is for. `IsFixedLenght` is to indicate if the field is either variable length like `varchar` or  fixed length like `char`.